# How to show an image in a modal/pop up in Laravel 5?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, modal-dialog

I am using Laravel 5 and have a visitor list. When I click one of the names of the visitor, it shows a modal and it contains the detail of it. But I don't know how to show a visitor photo on it? in my database, I only save the name of the file.
Here is the code to show the modal page:

```
<td>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editvisitor_modal" 
onclick="editvisitor_modal('{{ $Data->VST_ID }}'
                             , '{{ $Data->VST_NAME}}'
                             , '{{ $Data->VST_FROM}}'
                             , '{{ $Data->VST_MEET}}'
                             , '{{ $Data->VST_PURPOSE}}'
                             , '{{ $Data->VST_AGENDA}}'
                             , '{{ $Data->VST_PHONE}}'
                             , '{{ $Data->VST_EMAIL}}'
                             , '{{ date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($Data->VST_CHECKIN)) }}'
                             , '{{ $Data->VST_CHECKOUT}}'
                             , '{{ $Data->VST_PHOTO}}')">{{ $Data->VST_NAME }}
</a>
</td>
```

This is the javascript to throw the data to the modal:

```
function editvisitor_modal(VST_ID, VST_NAME, VST_FROM, VST_MEET, VST_PURPOSE, VST_AGENDA, VST_PHONE, VST_EMAIL, VST_CHECKIN, VST_CHECKOUT, VST_PHOTO) {
  $('#edit_vst_id').html(VST_ID);
  $('#edit_vst_name').val(VST_NAME);
  $('#edit_vst_from').val(VST_FROM);
  $('#edit_vst_meet').val(VST_MEET);
  $('#edit_vst_purpose').val(VST_PURPOSE);
  $('#edit_vst_agenda').val(VST_AGENDA);
  $('#edit_vst_phone').val(VST_PHONE);
  $('#edit_vst_email').val(VST_EMAIL);
  $('#edit_vst_checkin').val(VST_CHECKIN);
  $('#edit_vst_checkout').val(VST_CHECKOUT);
  $('#edit_vst_photo').val(VST_PHOTO);
}
```

And this is the code in my modal page:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Photo</label>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <img src="{{ asset('photos/tomas_logo.jpg') }}" width="40%">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Name<span class="required"> *</span></label>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <input class="form-control" id="edit_vst_name" name="edit_vst_name"  maxlength="100" placeholder="Visitor Name" value="" required>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that

```
function editvisitor_modal(VST_ID, VST_NAME, VST_FROM, VST_MEET, VST_PURPOSE, VST_AGENDA, VST_PHONE, VST_EMAIL, VST_CHECKIN, VST_CHECKOUT, VST_PHOTO) {
  $('#edit_vst_id').html(VST_ID);
  $('#edit_vst_name').val(VST_NAME);
  $('#edit_vst_from').val(VST_FROM);
  $('#edit_vst_meet').val(VST_MEET);
  $('#edit_vst_purpose').val(VST_PURPOSE);
  $('#edit_vst_agenda').val(VST_AGENDA);
  $('#edit_vst_phone').val(VST_PHONE);
  $('#edit_vst_email').val(VST_EMAIL);
  $('#edit_vst_checkin').val(VST_CHECKIN);
  $('#edit_vst_checkout').val(VST_CHECKOUT);
  $('#edit_vst_photo').attr("src","{{asset('your-image-folder/')}}"+VST_PHOTO);
}

<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Photo</label>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <img id="edit_vst_photo" src="placeholder.png" width="40%">
</div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

as noted in comments by @hendraspt it worked by adding '/'.

`$('#vstphoto').prop("src","{{asset('photos/')}}"+'/'+VST_PHOTO);`

Comment: It is still get the src value which is "placeholder.png" . I get an error `GET http://localhost/tomas/public/placeholder.png 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @hendraspt try to change attr to prop

Comment: is src not changing at all? is there any js errors?

Comment: it is not changing at all, still refer to `placeholder.png`. When I reload the page, I got an error in my console `GET http://localhost:8080/tomas/public/placeholder.png 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: I don't see any error in the js have you added the id to img? about placeholder you can remove it or add a plcaholder image

Comment: I figure it out. It is need '/'. `$('#vstphoto').prop("src","{{asset('photos/')}}"+'/'+VST_PHOTO);` would you like to edit your answer? Thank you

Comment: sure, I've did .

Answer (score 0):

u sure the image path is true?just use chrome view-source ,and find the path belongs to the pic, click it to see if It can show the pic .

just like this:

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).